# JqGrid client side searching problem

Tags: search, jqgrid, client-side

Hi guys I'm from Argentina I hope I can get myself understood. I'm having a problem trying to search from the client-side with jqGrid. The thing is that every time I search I get the ajax call to the server(I can see that with firebug). That's why I know it's not working... I use a json object to populate the grid(which comes from the database) and then I would like to allow the user to search but just the data that's on the grid.
My grid code is the one that follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#lista").jqGrid({
        editurl: $("#procesar").attr("href"),
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames:['Id',' Nº ','Punto', ' X (m) ',' Y (m) '],
        colModel :[
            {name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true, key: true},
            {name:'nroPunto', index:'nroPunto', width:55, sortable:false},
            {name:'punto', index:'punto', width:90, sortable:false, editable:true},
            {name:'coordenadaX', index:'coordenadaX', width:130, align:'right',
             sortable:false, editable: true},
            {name:'coordenadaY', index:'coordenadaY', width:130, align:'right',
             sortable:false, editable: true},
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowTotal: 2000,
        loadonce:true,
        mtype: 'GET',
        rowNum: 30,
        rowList: [20,40],
        pgbuttons: false,
        pginput: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 650,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Puntos de la estación total'
    });
    jQuery("#lista").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false, add:false,
        search:false, view:false, del:false}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {});
    jQuery("#lista").jqGrid('filterToolbar',
        {stringResult:true,searchOnEnter:true});});
```

If anybody can give me a clue or help me I would really appreciate that. Thanks for your time. Have a nice day.

**EDIT**

The JqGrid version I'm using is the latest 3.8.2 and the JSON object example is the next one:
{"total":"1","page":"1","records":"36","rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["1","200"," ","2000,000","2000,000"]},{"id":"2","cell":["2","201"," ","2000,014","3530,031"]},{"id":"3","cell":["3","202"," ","1992,448","2510,285"]},{"id":"4","cell":["4","203"," ","2006,621","2204,847"]},{"id":"5","cell":["5","204"," ","1991,831","2006,504"]},{"id":"6","cell":["6","205"," ","1991,965","2010,252"]},{"id":"7","cell":["7","206"," ","1992,033","2015,613"]},{"id":"8","cell":["8","207"," ","1878,381","2028,600"]},{"id":"9","cell":["9","208"," ","1986,948","2002,477"]},{"id":"10","cell":["10","209"," ","1992,027","1996,027"]},{"id":"11","cell":["11","210"," ","1991,994","1973,834"]},{"id":"12","cell":["12","211"," ","1992,103","1958,710"]},{"id":"13","cell":["13","212"," ","2006,499","2000,501"]},{"id":"14","cell":["14","213"," ","2006,375","1974,399"]},{"id":"15","cell":["15","214"," ","2053,375","1947,273"]},{"id":"16","cell":["16","215"," ","1999,762","1988,934"]},{"id":"17","cell":["17","216"," ","1993,516","1990,667"]},{"id":"18","cell":["18","217"," ","1993,048","1980,905"]},{"id":"19","cell":["19","218"," ","1993,552","1973,215"]},{"id":"20","cell":["20","219"," ","1992,298","1961,942"]},{"id":"21","cell":["21","220"," ","1993,996","1956,367"]},{"id":"22","cell":["22","221"," ","1994,533","1942,940"]},{"id":"23","cell":["23","222"," ","1992,991","1925,811"]},{"id":"24","cell":["24","223"," ","1998,680","1911,117"]},{"id":"25","cell":["25","224"," ","2003,728","1990,005"]},{"id":"26","cell":["26","225"," ","2003,374","1980,584"]},{"id":"27","cell":["27","226"," ","2004,817","1974,384"]},{"id":"28","cell":["28","227"," ","2007,155","1963,818"]},{"id":"29","cell":["29","228"," ","2008,765","1953,457"]},{"id":"30","cell":["30","229"," ","2007,731","1946,770"]},{"id":"31","cell":["31","230"," ","2006,323","1928,407"]},{"id":"32","cell":["32","231"," ","2005,959","1915,659"]},{"id":"33","cell":["33","232"," ","2016,908","1885,117"]},{"id":"34","cell":["34","233"," ","2197,893","1853,126"]},{"id":"35","cell":["35","234"," ","2203,655","1898,095"]},{"id":"36","cell":["36","235"," ","2334,684","1896,522"]}]}

Thanks Oleg for the advices I didn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove ',' (comma) before the close ']' in the definition of the `colModel` parameter. Syntax error can follow to very strange behavior.

If it will not help you should append your question with the JSON data which you catch from the server with the Firebug. Having this data everybody will be able to save the JSON data in the text file and reproduce your problem. You should write additionally which version of jqGrid you use.